# sql allocate values based on percentage

Tags: sql

Say I have a database with products and revenue.  I know that for the product 'Apple', we have many kinds of appples and roughly 70% of sales are granny smith and 30% are golden delicious.

```
select
        delivery_month_id,
        sales_order_id,
        product_id,
        product_nm,
        net_cost_distributed_amt,
from dw.op_sales_order    
where delivery_month_id >= 201601
```

What I have now is 
[image]

I'm trying to get something like this 
[image]

I'm assuming I need some case whens and sub queries but not entirely sure how to go about this.

Comment: So do you have 'Granny Smith, 70' stored somewhere?

Comment: Also, what's with the random assortment of data store tags? What environment are you trying to solve this for?

Comment: When you say "you know", do you mean you have another table that defines this percentage breakdown for each fruit?

Comment: Removed all tags except `sql`. Please choose the relevant database

Comment: I do not have another table that has granny smith, 70 stored somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You need a table (or similar row source, e.g., a `WITH` clause) with the product details.  Call it, for example `DW.PRODUCT_DETAILS`.  It should have three columns: `PRODUCT_DETAIL_ID`, `PRODUCT_NM`, and `ALLOCATION_PCT`, where `PRODUCT_NM` is the name as what appears in your `OP_SALES_ORDER` table.

Then, you can left join this table into your query to get your desired results:

```
SELECT so.delivery_month_id,
       so.sales_order_id,
       so.product_id,
       so.product_nm,
       so.net_cost_distributed_amt,
       so.net_cost_distributed_amt * NVL (pd.allocation_pct,1) rev_revised
FROM   dw.op_sales_order so 
       LEFT JOIN dw.product_details pd ON pd.product_nm = so.product_nm
WHERE  so.delivery_month_id >= 201601
```

With the left join, things like oranges and grapefruits, which do not have any details, will not need to be in the `PRODUCT_DETAILS` table.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without creating another table with the product details?

Comment: Or put another way, how could I create a temporary table that splits revenue 70/30?

Comment: Yes, there is a way.  Which database are you using?

Comment: I am using Hive